# How to set simple square grid as coordinate system in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I have a set of coordinates of drill sites that have x and y values ranging between 1-300. My task is to interpolate a 3D model out of them but that's easy. What I'm struggling with is setting a coordinate system that won't distort my point placement. The whole exercise is super basic that's why there is no predefined system just square x and y.

Comment: Do you mean your coordinates form a square that is arbitrarily rotated in regards to other existing coordinate systems?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you have a layer `grid` with an arbitrary cell size and a layer `points`, both in the same CRS (can be any CRS, does not play a role for this solution to work). On the points layer, use this expression to get x-coordinate values based on grid units, regardless of what the layer units are, and replace `7` at the end with the distance of one grid cell (and accordingly for y-coordinates):

```
($x - x_min (layer_property ('grid','extent'))) / 7
```

*I created a grid with 7m cell size, so I had to divide by 7; I also rounded the values to 1 decimal place; the values show x-/y-distance in grid units from the grid's origin (point at the bottom left of the grid):*
[image]

Answer (score 0):

All projected coordinate systems are just square xy grids.

The cartographic deformation is between the ellipsoid and the grid, but if you don't know their real world location or don't need to locate the points in the ellipsoid, you don't need to worry about deformations.

For non-georeferenced, arbitray local Cartesian systems I use **EPSG:3857**. This decision can be controversial, but it has some advantages:

- All negative and positive coordinates are valid and in the area of use of the system.
- It is well recognized by all web map libraries, so I can export to web maps, also in 3D.
- It is a kind of fantasy CRS anyways.

Just avoid measuring ellipsoidal lengths nor areas (don't use `$length` or `$area` functions in expressions, use `length(@geometry)` or `area(@geometry)` instead).